# EF Core - Reuse Table entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a database, which exists on 3 different stage servers.

The database is identical on all three servers.

I write an application to sync the database tables based on some logic.

For that approach i wrote an generic database context which contains the entites, because they are identical on all servers as well:

```
public abstract class GenericContext : DbContext
{
    public GenericContext(DbContextOptions<ContextA> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public GenericContext(DbContextOptions<ContextB> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public GenericContext(DbContextOptions<ContextC> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    [...]
}
```

The thought behind this was to handle the entites like `Application` centralized.

The entity Application looks like:

```
[Table("Applications", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Application
{

  public string Alias { get; set; }

  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [...]
}
```

In my startup class i register all 3 contexts with their matching DbContextOptions.

The reason for the approach is that my repositories expect a genric context to minimize the overhead to handle 3 different database types.
An example of this is:

```
public int AddApplication(GenericContext context, Application entity)         
{             
   context.Applications.Add(entity);  

   return entity.Id;
}
```

When i start my application everything works fine, until i try to access one of the contexts and they get actually build up.
Then the following exception is thrown:

```
 Cannot use table 'dbo.Applications' for entity type 'Application' 
 since it is being used for entity type 'Application' and potentially other
 entity types, but there is no linking relationship. 
 Add a foreign key to 'Application' on the primary key properties and 
 pointing to the primary key on another entity type mapped to 'dbo.Applications'.
```

As the exception states it seems to be not possible to reuse the table entity for multiple contexts.

Is there any way to manage the entities in the desired centralized way but avoid the exception?

Comment: Why? You can reuse the same `DbContext` with different connection strings.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, i edited my request to clearify it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the source of my error.

The entity `Application` was used in more than one of my contexts.

My thought was, that they were identically because the point to the same database table, but they differ in some of the navigation properties and so ef core correctyl states that the table is used more then once.

My solution was to unify the entity `Application` for both contexts.